# Calculation of time for submerged container to fill

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, water

I have been thinking on a proper way to calculate time taken to fully flooded a closed compartment with seawater once submerged. Only one small hole opening available for water to come in and air to escape.

This container is being submerged at a constant speed. As it being submerged, water rushed into the container and pushes the air out. But the rate of water coming in depends on differential pressure between inside (container internal volume which has air) and outside (seawater).

How to effectively calculate the exact time of the whole container will be filled with water and no more trapped air?

Constant:
container volume (considered rigid, no collapse)
submersion speed 
density of seawater wrt depth 
water temperature (assume as constant)
hole size (hole positioned on top of container)

Variable:
total time
final depth (seabed)

Comment: You are asking us to do a calculation for you. What have *you* tried? What part of the calculation are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Is this what is called "polydisperse gas-liquid flow"?

Comment: This is the kind of situation in which a calculation - even an estimate - would be quite difficult and probably unreliable. It would be far more sensible and easier to conduct experiments.